# What is the number by the Treasure Cave

Tags: card-wars-kingdom

[image: Treasure Cave]

My Treasure Cave has a little number next to it.  When the post office has that, it means there's letters for me to get.  What does the number mean on the Treasure Cave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this is the number of actions you can take in the chosen "Building" in this case the Treasure Cave, lets say you have 1000 gems and to buy cakes from the Treasure Cave costs 25 gems you will have 40 actions and so 40 in the red circle. The same is with the Dungeon however there the actions depends on hearts the cheapest battle is 5 hearts so if you have 20 hearts you will have 4 actions.